# How can I render DrawerLayout from react-native-gesture-handler on top of my TabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-gesture-handler

App using **react-navigation 6**

App have TabNavigator and I need to have Drawer that rendered on top of TabNavigator that render Items, that could be selected, and based on what Item was selected I need to change screen in the same Tab in TabNavigator.

The DrawerNavigator solution doesn't fit my needs. Because when user select another Tab from TabNavigator I should change Drawer content for another Tab and **lock** DrawerLayout on some Tabs

I tried to do the same with DrawerNavigator with CustomLayout but I can't get current routeName in DrawerNavigator to change content based on Tab, I could use TabPress listener but then how I could update DrawerNavigator route from TabNavigator?

I am using DrawerLayout to set up Drawer for my react-native app. And I just wrap TabNavigator with DrawerLayout like that(pseudo code):

```js
const TabNavigator = ({ route, navigation }) => {

    return (
      <DrawerLayout route={route} navigation={navigation}>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen>
          ...rest of tabs
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </DrawerLayout>
    )
}
```

And I am navigation to another screen in DrawerLayout like this when user press on Item:

```js
const onPressItem = () => {
   // if Item is not selected then navigate to new screen in the same tab
   if(TabSelectedItem !== 'New_Screen_In_The_Same_Tab') {
       navigation.replace('New_Screen_In_The_Same_Tab')
       navigation.setParams({
        TabSelectedItem: 'New_Screen_In_The_Same_Tab',
       })
   }
   // if tab was already selected close the drawer
   closeDrawer()
}
```

So basically everything works except one thing, I noticed that if I just close DrawerLayout everythings is fine, but when I am navigating to new screen I feel like DrawerLayout is lagging, I suppose it could be because I do navigation and all TabNavigator do re-render

Question is:
Could I fix it, or better to use any another solutions for this specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured out how to do this

Now I am using **Drawer** from [react-native-drawer-layout](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/main/packages/react-native-drawer-layout#readme)

I still wrap the **Drawer** around **Tab.Navigator**, but with this **Drawer** animations is smooth, in the case of **DrawerLayout** there is an [issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/2208#issuecomment-1249748435) with native animations, and when I do navigate to another screen inside **DrawerLayout** animation is a little bit glitchy, with **Drawer** everything is okay. It works in the same way as **Drawer.Navigator** from react-navigation

And to ***lock*** **Drawer** on some tabs I am using *getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute* from **react-navigation**. And inside **Drawer** I am checking if **currentRoute == selectedTabStack**
I pass **swipeEnabled={true}** to **Drawer** to be able to open **Drawer** with swipe gesture, and I have *open-drawer-button* only on those tabs where **Drawer** should be opened(configured via screen param *headerLeft*)

Also using *getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute* I change Drawer content based on *focusedRoute*(it would be the focused tab in my case)

Hope it will help someone :)